# Finding the area of the different portions of a rectangle that lie in a grid.

Tags: geometry, trigonometry, euclidean-geometry

I am an undergraduate student working on a large research project and one part involves calculating the portions of a rectangle that lie in different parts of a cartesian grid. In the figure below, I am trying to finding the portion of the grey rectangle that lies in each of the cells. Assume $\phi \in (0, \pi/2)$, and the width $W \le 1$, and $Q \in [0,1)$ (where $Q$ is the point at half the width $W/2$). While $\phi$ is given here as an angle, I am not using it as an angle because this is has to be coded and trig is expensive (it is given as such for easy descriptions in the paper I am working on). Instead I use the normal, $\vec n = [x, y]: \|  \vec n \| = 1$.

[image: Figure 1]

I have been working on this for a while, and I have a solution using many cases about where the corners lie and trigonometry to find these areas. However, this seems inefficient in retrospect (for example the image below which is a figure to describe finding the area in cell 2 given certain conditions - only the upper half of the rectangle is displayed for simplicity). I was wondering if anybody else had any ideas of methods that would be more elegant.

[image: Figure 2]

A couple other notes: The length is the distance from the entry point to the exit point of the center cell. I have a calculator programmed to give that, so in solutions you can just address it as $L$. Let $W$ be the entire width of the rectangle.

Thanks in advance.

**ADDITION:** As addressed in the comments, the total area of the rectangle is $W \times L$. The ray is the at the center the of the rectangle with length $L$ and rectangles of area $LW/2$ on either side. Also, the middle-right cell is supposed to be cell 6; the centermost cell is cell 5.

The rectangle is developed by the following: Pick a point on the left hand boundary of the center cell. Now draw a line from that point given that the angle between the line and the $x$ axis is between 0 and $π/2$. Now where that line hits the boundary of the cell is where it stops. This is $L$. Now on either side on this line, there are 2 rectangles of size $LW/2$. I want the area of these rectangles that lies in each cell

Comment: The width must be $\le 1$ but what is max height? Must part of the rectangle always be in the center square?

Comment: Yes. $Q$ is the vertical distance from the entry point to the bottom of cell 5 (upper boundary of cells 7, 8, 9), and $Q \in [0,1)$. The max height is given by point where the vector exits the cell 5.

Comment: I'm still confused. Does the rectangle not have some fixed width $W$ and some fixed height $H$? I saw the problem as randomly placing such a rectangle on your grid, with some part of the rectangle in the central cell, and then calculating how much of the rectangle's area was in each cell.

Comment: The rectangle is developed by the following: Pick a point on the left hand boundary of the center cell. Now draw a line from that point given that the angle between the line and the $x$ axis is between 0 and $\pi/2$. Now where that line hits the boundary of the cell is where it stops. This is $L$. now on either side on this line, there are 2 rectangles of size $LW/2$. I want the area of these rectangles that lies in each cell.

Comment: Now it's clear. I suggest you add that description to your OP.

Comment: So, $L = \min( 1/\cos\phi, (1-Q)/\sin\phi)$, $0 \lt L \le \sqrt{2}$, then?

Comment: Yes, that is correct.

Comment: There are many different cases you need to handle separately (depending on which cells the rectangle edges intersect, and also which cells contain a rectangle vertex), so I wouldn't look for simplification there. However, in many cases there are simple ways to calculate the areas. In your example, the area of the upper triangle is $y^2/\sin(2\phi)$, if the dotted vertical line is $y$. This is because $\tan(\phi)=y/b_1$ and $\tan(\pi/2-\phi)=y/b_2$, so the area of the triangle is $y(b_1+b_2)/2 = y^2/(2\sin(\phi)\cos(\phi))=y^2/\sin(2\phi)$.

Comment: Another approach to calculate the areas of the sub-triangles is to utilize the slope of $L$, $k_L = n_y/n_x$. Then, the slope of $W$ is $k_W = -1/k_L = -n_x/n_y$ (since it is perpendicular to $L$). In that case, $u = W k_L$, $L = \sqrt{1+k_L^2}$, and $P = Q + k_L$. It gets very complicated before you get to the simple results, so unit testing each case visually (I use scripts drawing SVG files) helps a lot.

Comment: I have solved almost all the cases using methodology very similar to what you are describing in your second comment. I guess there is no simpler way. However, testing is a big issue for me (I am kind of assuming my calculations are correct thus far, which is not good). Could you please explain what mean by unit testing?

Comment: Also in your comment, shouldn't $u = W \times k_{Wx}$ (the $x$ component of the slope of $W$).